# Set the right content type to upload an image in angular / node

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, content-type, forms

I use angular 6 and node 8 and I try to create a mechanism to upload images via a form .

So, this is my reactive form

```
<form [formGroup]="imageUpload" (ngSubmit)="imageUploadSubmitted()" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
  <input type="file" formControlName="imageInput" required #imageInput id="imageInput" name = 'image' (change)='imageChange($event)' accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif" > 
  <input type="text" formControlName="imageName" required>
  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>  
</form>
```

Every time you pick an image, save that image file in a File type variable

```
      selectedFile:File=null;
      imageChange(e){        
        this.selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
      }
```

Then send the form data to a service

```
  imageUploadSubmitted(){
    let input = this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput as any;        
    input.value = this.selectedFile;  
    this.myService.uploadImage(this.imageUpload.value).subscribe((data) =>{
      if(data.success){                  
        alert('all good');
      }
      else{
        alert('nope');
      }
    })
  }
```

This is the service

```
  uploadImage(data){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Authorization',this.user_token);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/cms/upload/image', data  ,{headers:headers}  ).pipe(map(res => res.json()));  
  }
```

So I have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the HTML part and I also append `'Content-Type','multipart/form-data'` in the service before sending.

In node when I `console.log('FILES - ',req.body);`, I get no files, its empty. I also get an error message `Error: bad content-type header, no multipart boundary`.

I also tried removing the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` HTML part or the `'Content-Type','multipart/form-data'` service part, just in case the right types are automatically set, but no luck.

Any suggestions on how to fix this, so I can get the files in node ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content type is added automatically, but you need to use `FormData` for your image.

```
let formData:FormData = new FormData();  
formData.append("imageInput", data);
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/cms/upload/image', formData);
```

This will automatically add the correct header (with boundary) for you

If you have several form fields you want to add, you can do:

```
(ngSubmit)="imageUploadSubmitted($event.target)"
```

To pass the form element, and

```
imageUploadSubmitted(form){  
    let formData = new FormData(form);
```

To create the `FormData` instance with the fields as well

Comment: Thanks. I will test it. But consider this : say my form has 4 text fields and not just one. So I cannot use the `<form>` I already have and I have to append all my text fields and my image to a new `FormData()` ? I am not saying that you are wrong. I just think is double work to have a form and use another Form object to post. How can I do this, using the one html form I already have? Thanks

Comment: You can pass your `form` tag to the constructor of `FormData` instead. Alternately, you can just use the form to submit your data and cut out the HTTP service entirely

Comment: I put no `enctype` in html and no `Content-Type` in service. I get `'C:\\fakepath\\myimg.jpg'` as the image value in node, that looks like wrong. Then I put the image input outside the `<form>` tag in HTML and erase the image value control from angular. So its now a form with only text fields. Then, before the post, I take the value of the image input, append it to the form and then send the form `this.imageUpload.addControl('newImage', new FormControl(this.selectedFile));` . And I still get empty file in node. How can I pass the form tag to the constructor of `FormData` ? Thanks

Comment: @slevin If you check the browser developer tools, if the data being sent correctly?

Comment: If I use the append solution or if I leave the file input in html form , I see the POST in the Network tab. The Headers are there but the preview is empty...Still, the texts got to the server but the image does not.

Comment: The preview tab is for checking the response. Depending on which browser you're using, you should be able to see the request, including the filename. If you can see it, then the problem is in the backend, not the Angular app. Can you create a StackBlitz or similar that reproduces your problem please?

Comment: Sorry for taking me so long, I was testing some code and then I tried to set a stackblitz, but there are errors that I cannot fix. Anyway, you can see my code [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ravte8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: That wasn't creating a `FormData` object to start with. Try [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m1h57l?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: `console.log('body - ',req.body);` in node gives a weird JSON with objs , one for each form control, like  `'0':
   { __zone_symbol__changefalse: [ [Object] ],
     __zone_symbol__inputfalse: [ [Object] ],
     __zone_symbol__blurfalse: [ [Object] ],
     __zone_symbol__compositionstartfalse: [ [Object] ],
     __zone_symbol__compositionendfalse: [ [Object] ] },` etc etc
I just parse the files and fields with formidable in node and the code never gets there, it stops in that first `console.log`. I see the same JSON in chrome dev tools, no image.

Comment: There shouldnt be JSON in the chrome dev tools, nor an image... It should look something like `------WebKitFormBoundaryaUC0VdtTaHH6OyxG
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="imageInput"; filename="myimage.png"
Content-Type: image/png`

Comment: Try uploading one from that Stackblitz I posted earlier, and take a look at the request in chrome dev tools. Just make sure your request looks similar

Comment: Oh man, thanks. I missed a line, now it works. [This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m1h57l?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) stackblitz saved me. So, passing the `$event.target` in the form submit, to the service function and using it to build a `FormData` before posting is a nice solution. Plus its not a hack and it uses only Angular and JS , no extra add-ons or packages. I was hoping for a package-free solution, we dont need to use packages for small, basic things, and you helped me create this. Thanks.

Comment: Also please consider incorporating the logic/solution of this stackblitz to your answer, so others can find it quickly. Thanks